# Separate font and color of words in grouped header UItableview

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont, uitableview

I have three strings that I want to present in header of grouped tableview. Problem is I append this strings in `tableView titleForHeaderInSection` and I want to present each string in different line with different color and font.

What currently I have is :

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

I get and append those three string as following

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section 
{

    NSString * presenter = [[self agenda] getBriefingPresenter:section];
    NSString * time = [[self agenda] getBriefingTime:section];
    NSString * subject = [[[[self agenda] getMeetingBriefings] objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"subject"];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@  %@", subject, time, presenter ];

}
```

Method to handle the header font

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    if (sectionTitle == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(45, 0, 484, 23);
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Century Gothic" size:17];
    label.text = sectionTitle;
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label.numberOfLines = 2;
    [label sizeToFit];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Create header view and add label as a subview
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 320, 400)];
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
}
```

So how can I parse this  `sectionTitle` and print as three different labels in three lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`, create 3 different labels with specific font and colors. You can't set different fonts/colors on a single UILabel;

So your code updated :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString * presenter = [[self agenda] getBriefingPresenter:section];
    NSString * time = [[self agenda] getBriefingTime:section];
    NSString * subject = [[[[self agenda] getMeetingBriefings] objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"subject"];

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *presenterLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 0, 484, 23)];
    presenterLabel.textColor = presenterColor;
    presenterLabel.font = presenterFont;
    presenterLabel.text = presenter;
    presenterLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [presenterLabel sizeToFit];

    UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, presenterLabel.frame.size.height, 484, 23)];
    timeLabel.textColor = timeColor;
    timeLabel.font = timeFont;
    timeLabel.text = time;
    timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [timeLabel sizeToFit];

    UILabel *subjectLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, timeLabel.frame.origin.y + timeLabel.frame.size.height, 484, 23)];
    subjectLabel.textColor = subjectColor;
    subjectLabel.font = subjectFont;
    subjectLabel.text = subject;
    subjectLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [subjectLabel sizeToFit];


    // Create header view and add label as a subview
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
    [view addSubview:presenterLabel];
    [view addSubview:timeLabel];
    [view addSubview:subjectLabel];

    return view;
}
```

and you don't need the `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section`

Comment: thank you but when I remove `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section` title or header  area shrinks to zero and there is no gap beetwee grouped tableviews

Comment: You just need to subclass `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` and return the proper height

Comment: Just added `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section 
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n \n \n"];
}` It works but I dont know if it is good solution for me

Comment: As I said, delete that it's dirty coding ! Instead add this `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { return theHeightYouWantForYourHeader; }`